# How do I get DOM from Chrome Remote Debugging

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I've been trying to get the DOM object with Chrome Remote Debugging using chrome-remote-interface with no luck (code is in node.js)

```
var Chrome = require('chrome-remote-interface')

Chrome(function (chrome) {
  chrome.on('Page.loadEventFired', function(evt) {
    console.log('load event fired')
    chrome.DOM.getDocument(null, function(resp) {
      console.log('DOM DOC')
      console.log(resp)   
    })
    chrome.DOM.getOuterHTML({}, function(resp) {
      console.log('outerhtml')
      console.log(resp)
    })
  })
  chrome.Debugger.enable()
  chrome.DOM.enable()
  chrome.Network.enable()
  chrome.Page.enable()
  chrome.Page.navigate({'url': 'https://github.com'})    
}).on('error', function () {
  console.error('Cannot connect to Chrome')
})
```

When running the file I've got these output

```
load event fired
DOM DOC
false
outerhtml
true
```

Answer (score 4):

turns out it was wrong callback handler, first parameter was for error not response. doh!

```
chrome.DOM.getDocument(null, function(err, resp) {
  console.log('DOM DOC')
  console.log(err)
  console.log(resp)

  // chrome.close()
})
chrome.DOM.getOuterHTML({}, function(err, resp) {
  console.log('outerhtml')
  console.log(err)
  console.log(resp)
})
```